# Glob / minimatch: How to get sub folders?

Tags: regex, npm, bower, glob, minimatch

I would like to copy the complete folder structure (without first level files) of a bower component into my web project.

The structure of the source projects looks like this:

```
bower_components/roboto-fontface-bower/css/
bower_components/roboto-fontface-bower/fonts/
bower_components/roboto-fontface-bower/.bower.json
bower_components/roboto-fontface-bower/bower.json
bower_components/roboto-fontface-bower/LICSENSE
bower_components/roboto-fontface-bower/package.json
bower_components/roboto-fontface-bower/README.md
```

I would like to get the folder `css` (with included files) and `fonts` (with includes files).

My current [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) pattern is:

`"bower_components/roboto-fontface-bower/**"`

With my current pattern, the files `.bower.json`, `bower.json`, etc. are also copied which is what I don't want. How can I only get the two folders (css & fonts)?

I tried `"bower_components/roboto-fontface-bower/{css/,fonts/}"` but this copies nothing.

Comment: What about `bower_components/roboto-fontface-bower/(css|fonts)/`? I'm not familiar with minimatch though so maybe that won't work.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but this didn't copy the `roboto-fontface-bower` folder at all. :'(

Comment: I'm not sure how the minimatch works so this might be outside of my area. With this regex the css and fonts directory should be returned isn't that what you are after or is there more to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `bower_components/roboto-fontface-bower/{css,fonts}/*`

You can test it using [globster.xyz](https://globster.xyz/?q=bower_components%2Froboto-fontface-bower%2F%7Bcss%2Cfonts%7D%2F*&f=bower_components%2Froboto-fontface-bower%2Fcss%2Fstyles.css%2Cbower_components%2Froboto-fontface-bower%2Fcss%2Freset.css%2Cbower_components%2Froboto-fontface-bower%2Ffonts%2Ffont1.ttf%2Cbower_components%2Froboto-fontface-bower%2Ffonts%2Ffont2.ttf%2Cbower_components%2Froboto-fontface-bower%2F.bower.json%2Cbower_components%2Froboto-fontface-bower%2Fbower.json%2Cbower_components%2Froboto-fontface-bower%2FLICSENSE%2Cbower_components%2Froboto-fontface-bower%2Fpackage.json%2Cbower_components%2Froboto-fontface-bower%2FREADME.md)